# Dagger error -no code generation on module

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, dagger

I cant compile my project with dagger, its showing the following error in the logs:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Module adapter for class myproject.org.modules.ActivityModule could not be loaded. Please ensure that code generation was run for this module.
```

My project works fine if i comment out the object graph so i know its set up right.

Here is my MainApplication class that extends application in android:

```
public class MainApplication extends Application {

    private ObjectGraph objectGraph;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(new ActivityModule());
        objectGraph.inject(this);
}
    }
```

And here is the only module i have:

The ActivityModule.java class is below:

```
@Module(
        injects=
                ListPageActivity.class

) 
public class ActivityModule { }
```

Here is my gradle build dependency:

```
dependencies {
compile files('libs/volley.jar')
apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:3.0+"          
compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:3.0+"  
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.2'
compile 'com.squareup:javawriter:2.5.1'
compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'


compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

}

and here is my project gradle build file:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0+'
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4+'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

For some reason i dont think this is dagger related, am i missing  a package or config in my IDE ? I've searched SO already and tried including javawriter for a dependency but its not resolving this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add

```
apt 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.2'
```

to your dependencies, so that the code-generation will run over your classes.

Comment: in your projects build.gradle file you need to install the gradle-android apt plugin.  add this to your dependencies in projects build.gradle : classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4+'

Comment: j2emanue's original example code in the original question was what I was assuming - it includes the installation of the apt plugin.